# mySQL REGEXP match value between commas

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I've been looking into the REGEXP when filtering my entries in my database.
I have a columns with values separated by commas looking like:
id        col A
|---|------------------------|
| 1 | P:1,P:2,P:5,P:7     |
| 2 | P:6,P:8,P:10,P:11 |
| 3 | P:4,P:3,P1,P:0      |
| 4 | P:2,P:1                 |
|---|------------------------|

Let's say I want the rows containing the value P:1, how can i design a REGEXP in the form:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `col A` REGEXP '?'
```

so that i get rows 1 3 and 4? My previous approach was simply to use:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `col A` LIKE 'P:1'
```

However that would naturally also return row 2 because it technically contains P:1...
Any help would be appreciated, I thinking this problem is fairly simple for a regexp expert!
Cheers,
Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read up on [word boundaries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html).

> [[:<:]], [[:>:]]
>
> These markers stand for word boundaries. They match the beginning and end of words, respectively. A word is a sequence of word characters that is not preceded by or followed by word characters. A word character is an alphanumeric character in the alnum class or an underscore (_).

Comment: Yep that is the answer: SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `col A` REGEXP '[[:<:]]P:1[[:>:]]'; Thanks a lot!